# wordpress order query by two meta keys

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to order posts by two meta keys "post_up_lvl" (dominant) and "post_up_exp".

For ex. output must be 44321111. If post_up_lvl repeat must order by post_up_exp where the date is stored. I tried that, but it arranges only by "post_up_lvl".

```
$qargs1 = array(

                'post_type'         => 'post',
                'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                'paged'             => $paged,
                'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                'levels' => array(
                    'key'     => 'post_up_lvl'
                ),
                'dates' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => 'post_up_exp', 
                        'value' => $today, 
                        'compare' => '>=', 
                        'type' => 'datetime' 
                    )
                )
                ),
                'orderby' => array(
                 'levels' => 'DSC',
                 'dates' => 'DSC'
                ),

                );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter `dates` doesn't exist, you must use `date_query` instead, I never heard about levels parameter in [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters),

Here is an idea for the meta_query and date_query, the array must remains, you can add/remove/modify arguments as your needs with the help of the link above,

```
    'meta_query' => array(
         'relation' => 'AND'
            array(
                'key' => 'post_up_lvl',
                'value' => $today,
                'type' => 'DATETIME'
            )
            array(
                'key' => 'post_up_exp',
                'value' => $today,
                'type' => 'DATETIME'
            )
    ),
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'post_up_exp',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'datetime'
        )
    )
```

Comment: I know how to use wp_query, but I don't get how to order by two keys :(

Comment: So you know that it can't work with dates and levels ;-) You can read about more about custom field https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters , date query, order. You query will never work with unknown parameters or arguments, in the example you have the basic meta_query array and date_query. Correct your query, try to var_dump($today) (to be sure). verify your date type. All the best.

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice the mistake. I fixed and now everything works.

Comment: Great ! Glad that you fixed it quickly. If you think it can help anybody else, mark the answer as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
$qargs1 = array(

                'post_type'         => 'post',
                'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                'paged'             => $paged,
                'meta_query'      => array(
                    'relation'    => 'AND',
                    'level' => array(
                        'key'     => 'post_up_lvl',
                        'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
                        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
                    ),
                    'expire'    => array(
                        'key' => 'post_up_exp', // Check the start date field
                        'value' => $today, // Set today's date (note the similar format)
                        'compare' => '>=', // Return the ones greater than today's date
                        'type' => 'datetime,' // Let WordPress know we're working with numbers
                    ),
                ),
                'orderby' => array(
                    'level' => 'DESC',
                    'expire'    => 'DESC',
                        )
                );
```

fixed my query and now it works